# Should IDataErrorInfo.Error return all of the errors or just property level errors?

Tags: .net, wpf

I am reasking this question because it was closed as a duplicate of another question about a similar, but different, interface. The other interface, INotifyDataErrorInfo, does not necessarily have the same rules.

Should IDataErrorInfo.Error return all of the errors? Or should it return just the object level errors?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an interface so the question as to whether or not it needs to return a value for "Error" is determined by what is consuming it. As far as I can tell, WPF does not call Error and will work fine without it, but who knows what will call Error in the future. So I think it should return a value. I use it myself in cases to get a complete list of errors for a certain object (eg, when the user pushed the ok button). As a bit of a helper I have this function in code:

```
    public static string GetErrorsFromIDataErrorInfo(IDataErrorInfo source, params string[] columns)
    {
        return columns.Select(c => source[c]).Where(e => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e))
            .FlattenToString("\r\n");
    }
```

And then call it like this to return data for the Error call:

```
    string System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return GT.GetErrorsFromIDataErrorInfo(this, "Code", "Name"); }
    }
```

The only downside is that you need to specify the property names to call but this can't be avoided really. You could use reflection but that could be inefficent if Error is called in a Where.

BTW, FlattenToString is a function that I have defined to turn an IEnumerable into a string and GT (general tools) is a class I put general purpose functions in. Crappy name but it is short.